# validate only numeric but should not allow if the numeric is only 0

Tags: javascript

I tried with

```
onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 49 && event.charCode <= 57'
```

omitting 0 but i could not able to type 10 or 20 or any numeric values that has 0.

Note: I don't want to have `0` as a value to be typed in the `text` field.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'
```

because '0' is 48

**EDIT:**

```js
 document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("keypress", myFunction);
 
function myFunction(event)
{
   if(event.key >= '0' && event.key <= '9')
   {
      if(event.target.value.length == 0 && event.key == '0')
         event.preventDefault();
   }
   else
     event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myInput" name="myName" min="1">
```

Comment: I don't want to have 0 as a value to be typed in the text field.

Comment: But then onkeyepress is the wrong place to check your data...?

Comment: any other solution...?

Comment: Why you want to prevent the user to type a 0 at the begining? Isn't it enough if the user can't saveor what ever you want  it in that case .

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
onkeypress='return !isNaN(this.value) && Boolean(this.value)'
```

Comment: nothing has been typed in the text field using above code

Comment: @StackOverflow oh, can you share a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

i think if you don't want to allow 0 at start then you can use this function like `onkeyup="isNumberKey(event,this.id);"` on your textbox.

```
--This Function To check Only Number Keys
```

function isNumberKey(e,v) { var t = e.which ? e.which : event.keyCode; if ((t >= 48 && t <= 57) || (t >= 96 && t <= 105) || (t == 8 || t == 9 || t == 127 || t == 37 || t == 39 || t == 46)) AvoidZero(v); return false; }

```
--This Function To avoid 0 at start
```

function AvoidZero(v) { var V = document.getElementById(v).value; return (V.charAt(0) == 0) ? (document.getElementById(v).value = V.substring(1, V.length), false) : false; }

this will prevent user to type single 0 but you can type 0 with any number like 10 20 30 40